# Selenium IDE - storeval- how to copy and paste

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

3 security questions appearing on the screen like in random order like 1,3,2 or 2.1 and then 3:

1. Pets name? 2. City you were born? 3. School you attend?

Lets say that answer is a last word of  each question. How to code it in Selenium ide. I guess to use GoToif, GotoLabel and StoreEval? Also, the answer should be stripped to one last word without space and "?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store text or value in Selenium IDE.

- The Command : storeText | storeValue (or storeAttribute if you want to stora an attribute of the element)
- The Target must be a css or an xpath expression which can localize the appropriate element
- The Value is the name of the new local variable in your Selenium IDE script

After using store command you can use your new variable like this: ${yourNewVariable}

For example:

```
storeAttribute  xpath=//div[@id='name-day']@name  nameday
echo  ${nameday}
```

You can use while loop and goto function in selenium ide with this addon : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flow-control/

Some commands:

- gotoif
- while
- gotolabel

Example:

```
store   1   answers
while   storedVars.answers <= 3 
echo    ${answers}
... 
store   javascript{storedVars.answers++;}   
endWhile
```

Comment: Could you give me an example using my code? Also, how to chose last word without space and "?" or I can parameterize and use AssertTeextPresent in Question 1, Question 2, Question 3 and then GoToLabel if not present. If peresent type ${answer}